# firefox addon tabs.activeTab is undefined

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs, firefox-addon

The tabs.activeTab is undefined :(
This works fine on ubuntu and windows machine. But does not work on mac machine. The firefox browser version is 47+.

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

function handleClick() {
  console.log(tabs.activeTab);
}

handleClick();
```

Answer (score 4):

After so much of research and headache.
I realized that our tester had turned off "Remember history" preference of the firefox browser. Because of this, I wasn't able to access the tab :(

PS : Its not OS specific.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for this share, I didn't expect remebering history would blocking accessing of the tab.